# The '$' command outputs "command not found"

Tags: 12.04

The '$' command gives the result and then outputs "command not found" in the terminal?

Comment: There is no '$' command so the message is accurate. It may be helpful to know what you were attempting to accomplish so we could be of more help. At the command line you can enter: filenames for files in your PATH, and shell commands and aliases. You can use the `apropos keyword` and then `man command_name` to find information about the former, and a command like `man bash` (if you use the bash shell) to find information about the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original question listed '$0', which is a positional parameter, not a command.

To display it's value without an error you should use

```
 echo "$0"
```